# Azure Webjobs System.UnauthorizedAccessException when accessing certain files inside WEBJOBS_DATA_PATH folder

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, kudu

A file I created through a webjob in its WEBJOBS_DATA_PATH folder (resides under "D:\home\data\jobs\continuous\WEBJOB_NAME\CANNOT_DELETE.file") can't be deleted giving back various errors based on the method with which you try to access it:

- Trying to download from the kudu file explorer: **System.UnauthorizedAccessException**
- Trying to delete via FTP: **550 Access is denied.**
- Trying to delete via Powershell console: **Cannot remove item D:\home\data\jobs\continuous\WEBJOB_NAME\CANNOT_DELETE.file: Access to the path 'D:\home\data\jobs\continuous\WEBJOB_NAME\CANNOT_DELETE.file' is 
  denied.**

Searching from the process explorer, no handles turn up if searching for the file.

It also happens randomly, usually to files which are written to and deleted often.

Stopping the website and all the webjobs doesn't help.

Any idea on how to remove the locked file (or at least find which process is currently holding its lock)?

Comment: Based on your description, this issue happens randomly. I have tested on my side, everything works as except. Could you provide a simple code for us to reproduce this issue? The detailed steps to reproduce this issue will be better.

Comment: Unfortunately, as it happens randomly, I have not yet been able to reproduce the issue consistently. In fact, I have currently 4 Node.js webjobs that use the same code to write a log file: only one of these log files is currently locked. I already had to delete and recreate a website more than one time, as it's the only way to get rid of the locked file.